# Is JetCreator still maintained (and/or is JETPlayer deprecated?)

Tags: android, wxpython, android-mediaplayer

My Android app requires several music *tracks* to be played back simultaneously and in sync (e.g. a drum track and a vocals track which play together, but which can be individually muted). Efforts with `SoundPool` have been fruitless -- even if I call `SoundPool.play()` in two sequential lines, there is always a perceptible delay introduced.

The [JetPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/JetPlayer.html) class seems perfect for what I need, but it also seems like nobody is using it -- the docs were last updated four years ago, the site of the maintainers is down, and the related [JetCreator](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/jet/jetcreator_manual.html) tool doesn't run on modern versions of Python, wxPython (crashes with wxPython C++ assertion) with no obvious workarounds/FAQs.

**Question:** Is JetPlayer/JetCreator abandonware, or should I still keep fighting with getting it to run?

**Corollary:** If it's still in use, can anyone advise on the following `wxPython` errors?

> ```
>   File "/usr/local/lib/wxPython-3.0.0.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-osx
>   _cocoa/wx/_gdi.py", line 5317, in __init__
>      _gdi_.AutoBufferedPaintDC_swiginit(self,_gdi_.new_AutoBufferedPaintDC(*args, **kwargs))
> wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "window->MacGetCGContextRef() != NULL" 
> failed at /BUILD/wxPython-src-3.0.0.0/src/osx/carbon/dcclient.cpp(195) in wxPaintDCImpl(): using wxPaintDC without being in a native paint event
> ```

Answer (score 1):

As your question is pretty old i hope my answer still helps you or anybody else.

Install Python for JET Creator

As a read JETCreator is not supported in newer versions of python, therefore use:

- Python Version 2.5.4 (python-2.5.4.msi)
- wxPython 2.8 (wxPython2.8-win32-unicode-2.8.7.1-py25.exe)

follow this tutorial
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_jetplayer.html
for installing python and wxpython.
Installing Python and JETCreator can be pretty tricky so you must be very carefull.
I had to try it several times until it worked correctly.

You can then download DEMo-Data from github or anywhere else!
JETCreator reads in MIDI files and produces JETfiles

In the JETCreator you can now set MUTE-flags for your tracks.
You have to remeber the "dezimal-number" of the muteflag as they represent the "binary-number" of the muted tracks. You have to implement this number into your Android project.

Use your created data in eclipse:

LOAD Data

```
    mJet = JetPlayer.getJetPlayer();
    mJet.setEventListener(this);
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.demo);
    mJet.loadJetFile(afd);
```

CALL JETplayer

```
    mJet.clearQueue();
    mJet.queueJetSegment(0, 0, -1, 0, 0, (byte) 0);
    mJet.play();
```

SET MUTE flages, eg.: at on  OnClickListener

```
    mJet.setMuteFlags(0b1110, false); //0b1110 = 14
```

Relesae your JETPlayer when stopped

```
    mJet.release();
```

If there are any question, do not hesitate to ask!

PS:  MIDI files do not support "human voice" and therfore vocals can not be played.